# How to send output of two different Spout to the same Bolt?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have two Kafka Spouts whose values I want to send to the same bolt.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

```
TopologyBuilder b = new TopologyBuilder();
b.setSpout("topic_1", new KafkaSpout(...));
b.setSpout("topic_2", new KafkaSpout(...));
b.setBolt("bolt", new MyBolt(...)).shuffleGrouping("topic_1").shuffleGrouping("topic_2");
```

You can use any other grouping, too.

**Update:**

In order to distinguish tuples (ie, topic_1 or topic_2) in consumer bolt, there are two possibilities:

1) You can use operator IDs (as suggested by @user-4870385):

```
if(input.getSourceComponent().equalsIgnoreCase("topic_1")) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

2) You can use stream names (as suggested by @zenbeni). For this case, both spouts need to declare named streams and the bolt need to connect to spouts by stream names:

```
public class MyKafkaSpout extends KafkaSpout {
  final String streamName;

  public MyKafkaSpout(String stream) {
    this.streamName = stream;
  }

  // other stuff omitted

  @Override
  public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    // compare KafkaSpout.declareOutputFields(...)
    declarer.declare(streamName, _spoutConfig.scheme.getOutputFields());
  }
}
```

Build the topology, stream names need to be used now:

```
TopologyBuilder b = new TopologyBuilder();
b.setSpout("topic_1", new MyKafkaSpout("stream_t1"));
b.setSpout("topic_2", new MyKafkaSpout("stream_t2"));
b.setBolt("bolt", new MyBolt(...)).shuffleGrouping("topic_1", "stream_t1").shuffleGrouping("topic_2", "stream_t2");
```

In `MyBolt` the stream name can now be used to distinguish input tuples:

```
// in my MyBolt.execute():
if(input.getSourceStreamId().equals("Topic1")) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something
}
```

*Discussion:*

While the *second* approach using stream names is more natural (according to @zenbeni), the *first* is more flexible (IHMO). Stream names are declared by spout/bolt directly (ie, at the time the spout/bolt code is written); in contrast, operator IDs are assigned when topology is put together (ie, at the time the spout/bolt is **used**).

Let's assume we get three bolts as class files (no source code). The first two should be used as producers and both declare output streams with the same name. If the third consumer distinguishes input tuples by stream, this will not work. Even if both given producer bolts declare different output stream names, the expected input stream names might be hard coded in consumer bolt and might not match. Thus, it does not work either. However, if the consumer bolt uses component names (even if they are hard coded) to distinguish incoming tuples, the expected component IDs can be assigned correctly.

Of course, it would be possible to inherit from the given classes (if not declared `final` and overwrite `declareOutputFields(...)` in order to assign own stream names. However, this is more additional work to do.

Comment: Yeah, figured it out after a while .Thanks !!

Comment: `if(input.getSourceComponent().equalsIgnoreCase(topic_1))
{
//do something
}
else
{
//do something
}`

Adding this in the bolt to seperate the source component from the tuple

Comment: @user-4870385 I believe it is an anti-pattern, bolts should not know where tuples come from, it increases complexity and maintanability suffers. You can use streams, as it is more abstract than a component name.

Comment: @zenbeni I don't see any advantage in using stream names instead of component IDs to distinguish input tuples. Please see my extended answer (feedback is welcome).

Comment: @user-4870385 if you want to refactor the whole and adding a new bolt between these two, it is a better coupling by using streams instead of component id, otherwise it is tightly coupled, and you would have to change code. Only the topology should know which bolt is linked to another.

Comment: Sorry. But I disagree again. If you insert a new bolt in between, you can easily assign the name expected by the consumer when plugging topology together. However, you need to change the code if the newly inserted bolt's declared output stream does not match the expected input stream name of the receiver bolt. It's the same argument as I applied in my comment. Nevertheless, you are right, that this is not natural. It would be best, to implement producer's declares output stream name and consumer's expected input stream names in a configurable way for maximum (and natural) flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.  You can have any spout talking to same bolt.
Refer https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Tutorial.html  "Streams" section.