# More complicated correlations by rules

Tags: apache-storm

I've seen some support for aggregations and joins but there aren't much words about it,

I wonder if Storm can correlate between events when there is no explicit correlation-id.

For example, assuming I have 3 (may be more) Spouts that emit tuples which represents Person from different sources.

```
Spout 1:
Person: name, security_id

Spout 2:
Person: fullName, secId, email

Spout 3:
Person: email
```

The end of the pipe should be 1 list of merged tuples (fields should be combined from all tuples), I would like to merge the Person tuples based on conditions such:

```
Spout1.security_id = Spout2.secId
||
Spout2.email = Spout3.email

(may be more rules)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it seems that you need to do a "windowed Cartesian Product" (which is quite expensive). For this, you need to use `allGrouping` connection pattern for all spouts to a single join bolt. Furthermore, in you join bolt, you need to distinguish incoming tuples (ie, from which spout a tuple was emitted) using `input.getSourceComponent()` or `input.getSourceStreamId()`. See here for a discussion about both methods: [How to send output of two different Spout to the same Bolt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851311/how-to-send-output-of-two-different-spout-to-the-same-bolt/31854495#comment51772191_31854495)

The most tricky part is the buffering. Because you do not have any ordering guarantees and you don't know if a tuple might join in the future or nor, you need to buffer each incoming tuple for some time (best to use distinct buffers for the different sources). Each time you receive a tuple, you need to evaluate your complex predicate using all buffered tuples. The most difficult question to answer is, how long to keep tuple in the buffer. This question is application dependent as it is a pure semantical question. You need to answer it for yourself.